# Django: lock particular rows in table

Tags: database, django, locking, atomic

I have the following django method:

```
def setCurrentSong(request, player):    
  try:
     newCurrentSong = ActivePlaylistEntry.objects.get(
       song__player_lib_song_id=request.POST['lib_id'],
       song__player=player,   
       state=u'QE')
   except ObjectDoesNotExist:
     toReturn = HttpResponseNotFound()
     toReturn[MISSING_RESOURCE_HEADER] = 'song'    
     return toReturn
 
   try:
     currentSong = ActivePlaylistEntry.objects.get(song__player=player, state=u'PL')
     currentSong.state=u'FN'  
     currentSong.save()
   except ObjectDoesNotExist:  
     pass
   except MultipleObjectsReturned:     
     #This is bad. It means that
     #this function isn't getting executed atomically like we hoped it would be
     #I think we may actually need a mutex to protect this critial section :(
     ActivePlaylistEntry.objects.filter(song__player=player, state=u'PL').update(state=u'FN')

   newCurrentSong.state = u'PL'
   newCurrentSong.save()
   PlaylistEntryTimePlayed(playlist_entry=newCurrentSong).save()
   return HttpResponse("Song changed")
```

Essentially, I want it to be so that for a given `player`, there is only one `ActivePlaylistEntry` that has a `'PL'` (playing) state at any given time. However, I have *actually* experienced cases where, as a result of quickly calling this method twice in a row, I get two songs for the same player with a state of `'PL'`. This is bad as I have other application logic that relies on the fact that a player only has one playing song at any given time (plus semantically it doesn't make sense to be playing two different songs at the same time on the same player). Is there a way for me to do this update atomically? Just running the method as a transaction with the `on_commit_success` decorator doesn't seem to work. Is there like a way to lock the table for all songs belonging to a particular player? I was thinking of adding a `lock` column to my model (boolean field) and either just spinning on it or pausing the thread for a few milliseconds and checking again but these feel super hackish and dirty. I was also thinking about creating a stored procedure but that's not really database independent.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Locking queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) were added in 1.4.

```
with transaction.commit_manually():
  ActivePlayListEntry.objects.select_for_update().filter(...)
  aple = ActivePlayListEntry.objects.get(...)
  aple.state = ...
  transaction.commit()
```

But you should consider refactoring so that a separate table with a `ForeignKey` is used to indicate the "active" song.

Comment: How would that refactor have any different outcome? Would I still run into the problem of potentially adding two rows into it at the same time?

Comment: No, since you'd use `Meta.unique_together` to prevent multiple rows being inserted for the same player.

Comment: Ah, well that's a key point you left out ;). For now select_for_update should be perfect. But you're probably right and I should eventually the current song in a different table. Otherwise I image I'll have scaling headaches. Thanks for the answer though. It' seems to be just what the doctor (temporarily) ordered.

Comment: Just to double check, I `commit_on_success` instead of `commit_manually` right?

Comment: Whichever is appropriate for your situation.